# General derivation of Supervirasoro algebra

Tags: mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra, superconformality

I'm looking for a derivation derivation of the ($\mathcal{N} = 1$) Supervirasoro algebra (NS sector) that does't just apply to specific examples. Most books/papers either just cite the result, or study a specific theory, usually type I superstring theory. But it seems to me, that it should be possible to make some general assumptions (i.e. the theory is conformal and supersymmetric, in some sense) and derive the algebra, in the same way as one would in the non-SUSY case. I would be very grateful if anyone could provide me with such a derivation (or at least a sketch), if it exists!

Comment: Can you sketch how one derives a non-graded Lie algebra of your paradigm? Without a "theory", that is.

Comment: @CosmasZachos The usual method is the following: One considers the action of a conformal transformation $\varphi$ on spacetime, satisfying $\partial_\mu\varphi^\rho(x) \partial_\nu\varphi^\sigma(x) \eta_{\rho\sigma} = \Lambda(x)\eta_{\mu\nu}$. By expanding to first order (2d) one gets the Cauchy Riemann equations, meaning that the functions representing the Lie algebra can be combined into meromorphic vector fields. By then choosing generators $l_n = -z^n\partial_z$, and calculating the central extension, one finds the Virasoro algebra. There are a bunch of caveats, but that's the main idea.

Comment: This only nets the algebra as a realization/basis of the conformal transformation. So, what have you learned about the superconformal group?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I suppose, but knowing the algebra and assuming conformal symmetry, I can postulate the existence of a representation on the Hilbert space, right? As for what I've learned about the superconformal group? From this, nothing much. I guess it wouldn't make sense to talk about susy without fields, so my assumption is that I would somehow have to combine my knowledge of the conformal algebra with that of some supercharges (which come from, uh, somewhere), to somehow generate an extended superalgebra? But I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: You appear to be in a strange rabbit hole. There are lots of reviews of superconformal transformations, and how they generalize conformal ones, but I'm not sure whether/how you avoid them....

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/the-superconformal-algebra) as well as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/superconformal-algebra).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm not quite sure either... I think the main issue is that I don't really know anything about SUSY, so that I wasn't really sure how to look, or how to generalize methods from different situations ($d=1+3$ or $\mathcal{N}=2$, etc). But anyway - thanks! I'll have a look at the references you suggested.